# Real Time Forum Notification system

Tags: asp.net-mvc, signalr

Forum is place where lots of people ask question and same way many people give answer for the question.

i want that when some one will post question and whoever seeing that question opening that page and in the mean time if anyone give answer for that question then that answer will be broad cast to all user who is on that question page. i want to do it with signalr.

we know that signalr has hub and from there we can hit database periodically and fetch the status and inform all user about the status by broadcast but hitting db periodically may not be good approach rather when db will be updated then something will inform my hug with some data and then hug will broadcast that data to all user who is on that question page.

my 1st concern is when db will be updated how do i know programmatically ?
2nd concern how do i call signalr hub method from out side with data fetch from db?

so please guide me how could i know when db updated without polling technique rather i want something which push updated data to signalr hub automatically when db updated?

also another important question is how to inform signalr hub from out side with data or passing parameter ?  if possible discuss in details with some sample code. thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**First part**: I would create a hub then for each question there would be a signalr [group](http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/signalr-20/hubs-api/working-with-groups). So whenever someone opens up a question it would connect to that group. So the hub can notify the readers.

**Second part**: you need to notify the hub about the event so it can notify the subscribers. I would not do it with db polling. Use an event broker instead from your domain layer and whenever a new post is sent to the repository (I do not know exactly your architecture) you can raise a domain event about this and you can subscribe to it and forward to the hubs.

When I do it I subscribe to my domain events from a static config class when the App_Start stuff runs and from the static subscribers I get into the signalr hubcontext via `GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext<T>()` [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.aspnet.signalr.infrastructure.connectionmanager.gethubcontext%28v=vs.118%29.aspx)

So the notification flow is:

1. save answer
2. raise domain event
3. receive domain event in subscriber
4. get hub context
5. notify the appropriate signalr group

**Update** here is a great post about this kind of domain event usage from Jimmy Bogard: [link](http://lostechies.com/jimmybogard/2010/04/08/strengthening-your-domain-domain-events/)

But to make it simple: you basically put a mediator between your domain (save answer) and the hub notification system and so you decouple them in a generic way. The mediator can be as simple as a static class (although I usually use an ambient context). The event is basically calling this static class with our custom parameters and the mediator should notify the subscribers about it which can also be as simple as a `T -> Action<T>` mapping.

A very basic example:

```
public static class EventBrokerExample
{
    private static ConcurrentDictionary<Type, List<object>> _subscriptions =
        new ConcurrentDictionary<Type, List<object>>();

    public static void Subscribe<T>(Action<T> callback)
    {
        _subscriptions.AddOrUpdate(typeof(T), new List<object> { callback }, 
            (type, list) => new List<object>(list) { callback } );
    }

    public static void Send<T>(T message)
    {
        List<object> subscribers;
        if (_subscriptions.TryGetValue(typeof(T), out subscribers))
        {
            foreach (Action<T> subscriber in subscribers)
                subscriber(message);
        }
    }
}
```

You would use the `EventBrokerExample.Subscribe<SaveAnswerMessage>(handler)` from some startup code then you would use `EventBrokerExample.Send(new SaveAnswerMessage())` from your domain when you save a new answer.

Comment: All this can be done very easy with https://github.com/AndersMalmgren/SignalR.EventAggregatorProxy

Comment: i am not very advance developer. so it will be good help if u discuss more in detail for domain events and how to use it. thanks a lot.

Comment: thanks for more detail but i like to know when any new post will be saved in db then how to notify my signalr hub from out side.

Comment: u said :- Use an event broker instead from your domain layer. which event broker you were talking about? how my hub can be notified by event broker? please discuss. thanks

Comment: As I said you can get the hub context with GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext<T>() and so you can notify the group subscribers. I can not provide exactly what you have to write because I do not see your code. You have to raise the events when you save the answer and a listener on that event should get the hub context and notify their listeners too (the signalr group).